# list and data frames manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with one of the column "values". It contains -

```
values
[u'12f4',u'ff45',u'tr23']
[u'125g4',u'ff145',u'trr523']
[u'12f34',u'ff2345',u'trg23a']
```

I have a separate list 'list1' containing some of the values -

```
[u'trg23a',u'ff2345',u'ff45',u'fg567ui',u'45ty78',u'125g4',u'ff145']
```

I want to create a new column in df called "values1" containing only those values that exist in "list1". So output should be like -

```
values                            values
[u'12f4',u'ff45',u'tr23']         [u'ff45']
[u'125g4',u'ff145',u'trr523']     [u'125g4',u'ff145']
[u'12f34',u'ff2345',u'trg23a']    [u'ff2345',u'trg23a']
```

I have tried below code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
df['values1'] = [element for element in 
df['values'] if element not in list1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) or nested `list comprehension`:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'values']))
<class 'str'>

from ast import literal_eval
#convert string values to lists
df['values'] = df['values'].apply(literal_eval)

print (type(df.loc[0, 'values']))
<class 'list'>

df['values1'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: [element for element in x if element in list1])
print (df)
                    values           values1
0       [12f4, ff45, tr23]            [ff45]
1   [125g4, ff145, trr523]    [125g4, ff145]
2  [12f34, ff2345, trg23a]  [ff2345, trg23a]
```

Or:

```
df['values1'] = [[element for element in x if element in list1] for x in df['values']]
print (df)
                    values           values1
0       [12f4, ff45, tr23]            [ff45]
1   [125g4, ff145, trr523]    [125g4, ff145]
2  [12f34, ff2345, trg23a]  [ff2345, trg23a]
```

Comment: each cell within the column values1 is empty. It only contains []

Comment: This gives me - print (type(df.loc[0, 'values'])): <class 'tuple'>

Comment: I get the error - ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: Are data confidental? If not, is possible sent them to my email in my profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `filter`, although conditional list comprehensions like that used in @jezrael's solution is probably slightly more efficient.

You are basically running the filter lambda expression on each item in the df['values'] column.

```
values = [u'trg23a',u'ff2345',u'ff45',u'fg567ui',u'45ty78',u'125g4',u'ff145']

df = df.assign(
    values1=df['values'].map(
        lambda row_items: filter(lambda item: item in values, row_items)))

>>> df
                    values           values1
0       [12f4, ff45, tr23]            [ff45]
1   [125g4, ff145, trr523]    [125g4, ff145]
2  [12f34, ff2345, trg23a]  [ff2345, trg23a]
```

Comment: I get the error - ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: Given that you got this error with both my solution and that of @jezrael, it seems that you have some malformed data.  I would first try to isolate the dataframe causing the problem and then try to subset the dataframe to find the bad data.